# How do I handle checkbox's onChange in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Im begginer in React programming, and need some help. I got simple component, that uses useState and useEffect hooks. This components is getting a number (as props), how much checkboxes should it render. It looks like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-wescoff-ji0zq?file=/src/App.js).

Why does handleCheckbox method returns an empty array?
Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Did you take a look at problems tab ? Replace `[index]` parameter in `useEffect` hook function with just `[]` and it will work as expected.

Comment: I tried, with [] returns an empty array as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, I spotted quite a few issues which are interlinked (thats okay, you're a beginner) so I am going to try untangle this with words.. the code is easy to untangle.

[Check out this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-beaver-k3q7l?file=/src/App.js)

the crux of the issue ? **Stale closures and async nature of setState**. So many people fall victim to this, and I have answered this question quite a few times in different ways. so don't stress.

React relies on rendering to ensure the latest state is contained with a functions `closure`. Think about a `closure` as a "snapshot" of variables at a specific point in time (or better yet, for a specific render cycle).

the useEffect in `Component` has an empty dependency array. This means, in short, that it will only ever call the code within the useEffect once, when the component first mounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
   //this code will run only once when the component mounts for the first time
   //index has no bearing since index is a value type which never changes in your example
   //useEffects always react to a change in value of a value type (number, boolean, etc) or if a reference changes of a reference type (spreading an object creates a new reference, for example)
},[])
```

Now back to stale closures: What the above useEffect does in your example, is create a "snapshot" of the values used in the `handleCheckbockChange` function, as they are on the first render when passed into the callback methods for onChange

see below here

```
  const handleCheckbockChange = (e, value) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;

    const states = [...buttonsState]; 

    const indexOfCheckBox = states.findIndex((el) => el.value === value);

    if (indexOfCheckBox !== -1) {
      states[indexOfCheckBox].visible = checked;
    }

    setButtonsState(states);
    console.log(states);
  };
```

now, remember what I said about "closures" being snapshots? when buttonState is created, it was initialized to an empty array

```
const [buttonsState, setButtonsState] = useState([]);
```

so on the first render, your function actually looks something like this in memory

```
  const handleCheckbockChange = (e, value) => {
    const { checked } = e.target;

    const states = [...[]]; //buttonStates is an emptyArray when this was created!

    const indexOfCheckBox = [].findIndex((el) => el.value === value);

    if (indexOfCheckBox !== -1) {
      [][indexOfCheckBox].visible = checked;
    }

    setButtonsState([]);
    console.log([]); //<-- EMPTY!!
  };
```

but you may now wonder how on earth this is possible if you are calling `setButtonsState` in the useEffect?

Well.. now we come to the async nature of setState.

setState batches the updates and only applies them on the next render, hence asyncronous.

Your `states` variable is initalised in the useEffect, **but only after** a closure around `handleCheckbockChange` was already created with your initial value of `[]`. Therefore,  handleCheckbockChange never gets this value since by that point the closure assigned to your onChange callback was already created with the initial value.

all your click actions therefore call the very first snapshot of `handleCheckbockChange` which ever gets the updated value of the `buttonsState`, because the useEffect runs only once.

**Solution**

[Check out this sandbox.. here again for reference](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-beaver-k3q7l?file=/src/App.js)

There are actually a few things you can do here, but the easiest way to solve your situation is to remove the creation of your components out of the useEffect, so they freely rerender getting the latest closure snapshot of `handleCheckbockChange` in their onChange handlers, everytime a change to `buttonsState` occurs.

Comment: Thank you. This explanation dispelled all my doubts. It turns out that I still have large gaps in knowledge. Nevertheless, your explanation helped me a lot and the problem was solved, thank you very much

Comment: absolute pleasure, wishing you all the best with your React journey.